# Did Henrietta Maria leave any writings in which she described her thoughts with respect to Charles I's afterlife?

Tags: england, catholic-church, monarchy, english-civil-war

**[Henrietta Maria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henrietta_Maria_of_France)**, Charles I's queen consort, was a famously strident Roman Catholic. She outraged her husband's subjects by praying publicly under the gallows at Tyburn, where many Roman Catholics had been killed for their faith, and, in private, attempted to convert her Calvinist nephew, Prince Rupert.

Her husband, **[Charles I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_I_of_England)** was [beheaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Execution_of_Charles_I) in 1649 at the close of the [English Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Civil_War), and Henrietta Maria survived him by over twenty years. Charles I was still a Protestant at the time of his execution. Is there any evidence as to what the queen dowager thought - or might have thought - regarding his eternal fate? **Did Henrietta Maria herself, or her courtiers (based on what Henrietta Maria had told them), leave any writings which elaborated on what Henrietta Maria thought had happened to Charles in afterlife?** Did she believe he was in heaven or in hell?

If she did not mention this or if this mention has not survived to our time, a general answer with respect to what being out of communion for Catholics of the mid-17th century meant is also suitable.

What spurred me to ask the question was reading about Henrietta Maria, and then recalling an article I had read a while ago about the many mixed marriages—Catholic and Protestant—in Europe during the Thirty Years War. Henrietta Maria and Charles I are the most famous example of such a marriage that I can think of, and seemed like an interesting test case of what such spouses might have thought about each other.

*Note: Current edits have incorporated suggestions and clarifications from the comments.*

Comment: Purgatory seems like reasonable choice for devout Catholic :)

Comment: That seems like a pretty legit question to me. I'd highly suggest editing that information into the question. That's objectively answerable with historical research, so I'd think we should be able to get a question around that reopened.

Comment: I agree with T.E.D. I think this is worth reopening. The OP is asking if there is *evidence* of what she thought. This doesn't seem opinion-based to me. Also, the fact that there may not be any evidence is not a reason for closing, I think, as it possible that there is evidence.

Comment: @LarsBosteen I'm still not convinced.  The question is asking what she _believed_ which is always going to be problematic.  An objectively answerable question might be whether she ever expressed an opinion as to whether Charles I went to Heaven/Hell/Purgatory (or, perhaps, whether she expressed an opinion about whether different rules applied to anointed monarchs than to everyone else).  What she actually _believed_ can only be inferred from her words & actions, and so is inherently _opinion-based_.

Comment: @LarsBosteen If the edit is going to change the intent of the question then (IMO) that edit should be made from by OP.  I'm always prepared to _suggest_ improvements, but in the end it is the OP's question, and they should be the one who decides whether to implement those suggestions or not.

Comment: @TomHosker: Do you mind if I try editing this further to make it even less opinion-based?

Comment: By all means. Do whatever you feel necessary.

Comment: @TomHosker: There it is :)